# Pygame throws "TypeError" when creating a custom sprite class

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to create a scenery with images moving in different speeds from one side of the screen to the other, creating a parallax effect. I use a sprite class I called BackgroundObject, but when I try to create a Sprite using BackgroundObject, I am getting a TypeError.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys, random, os
import vector

# Background objects (for parallax)
class BackgroundObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def _init_(self, x, y, image, speed):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
    self.image = image
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
    self.speed = speed

  def update(self, time_passed):
    moved_distance = time_passed * self.speed
    self.rect.left += moved_distance
    if self.rect.right < 0:
      self.rect.left= self.rect.width


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((768, 1024), 0, 32)

obstacleImage  = "obstacle.png"
fenceImage = "fences.png"
cloudImage = "clouds.png"
cityImage = "cityscape.png"
groundImage = "bottom.png"
backgroundImage = "background.png"

pathName = "Assets"

# Sprites in the game
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
backgrounds = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()
backgroundOrder = []
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + os.sep + backgroundImage))

fences = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + os.sep + fenceImage))
clouds = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + os.sep + fenceImage))
cityscape = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + os.sep + cityImage))
ground = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + os.sep + cityImage))

sprite = BackgroundObject(1280, 192, clouds, 192)
backgrounds.add(sprite)
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(0, 192, clouds, 192))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(832, 768, cityscape, 154))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(0, 768, cityscape, 154))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(1728, 768, fences, 384))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(0, 768, fences, 384))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(992, 896, ground, 512))
backgrounds.add(BackgroundObject(0, 896, ground, 512))

titleScreen = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(pathName + backgroundImage))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      exit()

  screen.blit(titleScreen, titleScreen.rect)

  backgrounds.update(time_passed)

  backgrounds.draw()

  for item in background:
    if item.rect.right < 0:
      item.rect.right += (item.rect.width * 2)
```

The error message I am recieving is as follows, and I can't make sense out of it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    sprite = BackgroundObject(1280, 192, clouds, 192)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 114, in __init__
    if groups: self.add(groups)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 129, in add
    else: self.add(*group)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 129, in add
    else: self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `__init__`; use **two** underscores before and after:

```
class BackgroundObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
        self.speed = speed
```

Your traceback shows `BackgroundObject()` goes straight to `Sprite.__init__` without first passing through your method.

Comment: That did the trick! That's a mistake I'll never do again. Thank you!